# How to "Connect via Bluetooth" in WM programmatically?

Tags: windows-mobile, bluetooth, activesync

Does anybody know how do I programmatically emulate a click on ActiveSync "Connect via Bluetooth" menu? I need my smartphone to periodically attempt to check/reestablish connect via bluetooth, but I couldn't find anything in WM SDK, which would do that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [32feet.net bluetooth SDK](http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx).

Comment: can you give me a hint, which of the objects does it? I couldn't find any mentioning of activesync integration in this package